# Blog navigation overlaps blog text

Tags: bug, design, blog

The blog navigation overlaps the text, as visible in this screencap of the [current latest blogpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/):
[image: Stackoverflow text overlaying the blog text]

It's  quite a bit easier to spot over an image:
[image: Stackoverflow text overlapping an image in the blog]